# Check string for specific format of substring, how to..?

Tags: python, regex, string, compare, substring

Two strings. My items name:

> Parfume name EDT 50ml

And competitor's items name:

> Parfume another name EDP 60ml

And i have a long list of these names in one column, competitors names in other column, and I want to leave only those rows in dataframe, that have same amount of ml in both my and competitors names no matter what everything else in these strings look like. So how do I find a **substring** ending with 'ml' in a bigger string? I could simply do

`"**ml" in competitors_name`

to see if they both contain the same amount of ml.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

'ml' is not always at the end of string. It might look like this

> Parfume  yet another great name 60ml EDP

Comment: what about string1.split()[-1]==string2.split()[-1] ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the python Regex library to select the 'xxml' values for each of your data rows and then do some logic to check if they match.

```py
import re

data_rows = [["Parfume name EDT", "Parfume another name EDP 50ml"]]

for data_pairs in data_rows:
    my_ml = None
    comp_ml = None

    # Check for my ml matches and set value
    my_ml_matches = re.search(r'(\d{1,3}[Mm][Ll])', data_pairs[0])
    if my_ml_matches != None:
        my_ml = my_ml_matches[0]
    else:
        print("my_ml has no ml")

    # Check for comp ml matches and set value
    comp_ml_matches = re.search(r'(\d{1,3}[Mm][Ll])', data_pairs[1])     
    if comp_ml_matches != None:
        comp_ml = comp_ml_matches[0]
    else:
        print("comp_ml has no ml")

    # Print outputs
    if (my_ml != None) and (comp_ml != None):
        if my_ml == comp_ml:
            print("my_ml: {0} == comp_ml: {1}".format(my_ml, comp_ml))
        else:
            print("my_ml: {0} != comp_ml: {1}".format(my_ml, comp_ml))
```

Where data_rows = each row in the data set

Where data_pairs = {your_item_name, competitor_item_name}

Comment: How to modify the code to look for ml not only at the end of string but anywhere in the middle?

Comment: It's not specific - this will just look anywhere in the string where ml appears after 1, 2 or 3 numbers.

Comment: @milka1117 Apologies - the Search returns an array of matched cases (which I forgot to add to my solution) I have since updated my code to be more explicit.

Comment: Marked it as the answer. And I already have one problem - what if any name does not have size provided, I mean, no 'ml' substring. I get error about: 
"'NoneType' object is not subscriptable". What to do in this case? If no size is provided, I want to mark it as "no match"

Comment: @milka1117 I have updated the code in the answer to satisfy the above comment.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```py
import re

def same_measurement(my_item, competitor_item, unit="ml"):
    matcher = re.compile(r".*?(\d+){}".format(unit))
    my_match = matcher.match(my_item)
    competitor_match = matcher.match(competitor_item)
    return my_match and competitor_match and my_match.group(1) == competitor_match.group(1)

my_item = "Parfume name EDT 50ml"
competitor_item = "Parfume another name EDP 50ml"
assert same_measurement(my_item, competitor_item)

my_item = "Parfume name EDT 50ml"
competitor_item = "Parfume another name EDP 60ml"
assert not same_measurement(my_item, competitor_item)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a lambda function to do that.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
d = {
    'Us':
        ['Parfume one 50ml', 'Parfume two 100ml'],
    'Competitor':
        ['Parfume uno 50ml', 'Parfume dos 200ml']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['Eq'] = df.apply(lambda x : 'Yes' if re.search(r'(\d+)ml', x['Us']).group(1) == re.search(r'(\d+)ml', x['Competitor']).group(1) else "No", axis = 1)
```

Result:

[image]

Doesn't matter whether `'ml'` is in the end of in the middle of the string.

Comment: 151 character oneliner, really?

Comment: @ruohola Why not? ;)

Comment: @milka1117 which version of Python are you using?